# Pulseaudio Windows Server and Debian (Linux) Client?

Tags: linux, audio, debian, pulse-audio

I am using pulseaudio to use a single set of speakers for both pc's on my desktop.

I am using windows as a server and have used the following tutorials to set it up:
[parseq setting up pulseaudio 1.0 beta](https://parseq.co.uk/wordpress/archives/setting-up-pulseaudio-1-0-beta-for-windows)
[On Ubuntu with graphical user interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28039/how-to-stream-music-over-the-network-to-multiple-computers)
[Linux Share sound across computers with pulseaudio](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/332418:weekend-project-using-pulseaudio-to-share-sound-across-all-your-computers)

So it is setup on the linux side and windows side and it is running(and audio coming through), `I assume` as pulseaudio.exe is using up CPU resources (about 0.1 - 0.3%). Also the linux side (pavucontrol) says `Simultaneous output to Built-in Audio Analog Stereo.

So I think it is ok, but o audio on Windows.

I use Debian Linux and windows 8.

Thanks.